# Spring Validation collections error

Tags: java, spring, validation, collections

I have a problem validating an array List with Spring.

Rest service

```
public ResponseEntity<?> editPeople(@RequestBody List<Person> people, BindingResult result ){
....
}
```

Person POJO

```
public class Person()
{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Integer getId(){
    return id;
  }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Validator

```
public class personValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
         ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "name", "name.empty");
    }
}
```

Also I Created a validator for the Person class. However anytime that I use the errors.rejectValue(..) I get the following error:

```
"Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?",
```

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the Person Pojo?

Comment: @netta I have added the POJO now

Comment: This is a wild guess but maybe try to change the int to Integer